# Eclipse Helios hangs while loading com.android.ide.eclipse.adt

Tags: android, eclipse

when eclipse is getting started up and while loading `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt`
It hangs while loading.
I have attached an image. tried out taking .markers file but no use.
Restarted the system and tried with starting eclipse again but the same problem.
I am using Windows 7, 64 bit operating system with core i5 with 4gb RAM.
Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things you could try:

- Start eclipse from a command line with -clean
- Manually remove ADT from the plugins/features directories of eclipse, then if it starts, reinstall ADT.

You did not indicate platform, so I cannot give you more detailed instructions on those two steps. Just look for them via google for your platform.

Comment: I have updated the question with platform, I am using Windows 7, 64 bit operating system, i5 processor with 4gb ram. thanks.

Comment: I manually removed the files and started eclipse and it got loaded, then closed down the eclipse added files of adt version 20 again and started the eclipse with no problem.But I  had two versions adt 15 and adt 20, so I only added adt 20 and adt overlay 20 and it worked perfectly. thanks.